# How to create a new text file in SVN using SVNKIT..?

Tags: java, eclipse, svnkit

As I am new to this SVNKIT . Please any  one Can provide me the code for creating an new text file SVN repository .

Eg: `file:///E:/SVN/IDS/MSCVE`

I want to add a new text file in the MSCVE folder.

it has to look like the below tree structure

```
file:///E:/SVN/IDS/MSCVE/newtextfile.txt
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: As SVN is just like a folders in PC. Code will be similar, as you create file in java. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the instructions in the SVNKit Wiki? See [Committing To A Repository](http://wiki.svnkit.com/Committing_To_A_Repository).

The following code adds the file `nodeC/itemC2`, adds the text and then changes some properties on it:

```
//the second and the third parameters are the path and revision respectively 
//of the item's ancestor if the item is being added with history
editor.addFile( "nodeC/itemC2" , null , -1 );

baseChecksum = ...;
editor.applyTextDelta( "nodeC/itemC2" , baseChecksum );

baseData = ...;
workingData = ...;
checksum = deltaGenerator.sendDelta( "nodeC/itemC2" , baseData , 0 , workingData , editor , true );
editor.closeFile( "nodeC/itemC2" , checksum );

editor.changeFileProperty( "nodeC/itemC2" , "propName1" , "propValue1" );
editor.changeFileProperty( "nodeC/itemC2" , "propName2" , "propValue2" );
```